# How do we define this unordered sum on the metric of the Schwarz space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

From a set of slides:
[image]

[image]

I am trying to understand how the metric on the Schwartz space is defined. So it is basically just an infinite series, but how do we actually sum over all $\alpha$, $\beta$ because, unlike normal series, this is not an ordered sum?

Comment: Instead of reading slides, why don't you consult a good textbook, or at the very least some good lecture notes? Slides are not for detailed study.

Comment: The sum converges absolutely, so you can order the terms any way you like